# Is it possible to have objects as members of enum

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have a list of which most naturally fits into an object:

```
{
    "book":"Name",
    "chapter":"2",
    "page":"3"
}
```

In my schema I would like to have a set of object which are acceptable:

```
enum: [{
    "name":"Whuthering Heights",
    "chapter":"44",
    "page":"365"
}, {
    "name":"Jane Ayer",
    "chapter":"1",
    "page":"2"
}]
```

So that a JSON could have only one of these to be valid.

Is this supported at all under draft 7?

BTW, a pointer to an on-line JSON schema verifier.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. `enum` values can be absolutely anything.

> Elements in the array might be of any value, including null.
>
> - http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.6.1.2

Comment: Did you mean to point to [`enum`](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.6.1.2) instead?

Comment: Ha! Yes, thanks for catching that. I've updated the answer. `const` and `enum` are basically the same thing ;-)